# Dark Mode set to local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

Hi I have a problem saving a setting a dark mode on my website to a `localStorage`, so after a refresh or transition to another page the setting would stay the same. Automatic change based on user preference is not needed. I actually have 2 bodies both with different colors and an icon which is changing depending on a light/dark setting.

JS:

```
var ImgSource = ["img/ModeDark.png", "img/ModeLight.png"];
var Index = 0;

function changeColor() {
    var body2 = document.getElementById("body2");
    var img = document.getElementById("DarkMode");
    document.body.classList.toggle("bodyDark");
    body2.classList.toggle("body2Dark");
    document.body.classList.toggle("body");
    body2.classList.toggle("body2");
    if (Index >= ImgSource.length) {
        Index = 0;
    }
    img.src = ImgSource[Index];
    Index++;
}

localStorage.setItem("dark", document.body.classList.contains("bodyDark") ? "bodyDark" : "body");
localStorage.setItem("dark2", document.body.classList.contains("body2Dark") ? "body2Dark" : "body2");

if (localStorage.getItem("dark") === "bodyDark") {
    changeColor();
} else if (
    localStorage.getItem("dark") !== "body") {
    changeColor();
}

if (localStorage.getItem("dark2") === "body2Dark") {
    changeColor();
} else if (
    localStorage.getItem("dark2") !== "body2") {
    changeColor();
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: mintcream;
    transition: color, background-color .5s;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
}

.bodyDark {
    background-color: #1a2022;
    transition: color, background-color .5s;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}
.body2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    height: max-content;
    transition: background-color .5s ease;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: black;
}

.body2Dark {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    height: max-content;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    background-color: #252c2e;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="heading">
        <button class="tile" onclick="changeColor()"><img id="DarkMode" alt="DarkMode" src="img/ModeLight.png" width="25"/>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="body2" id="body2">
        <h1>AAAAAAAA</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to create such a complex and unconventional system to switch color mode?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BülentAkgül HTML in the code is much more complex as the preview here. The reason is that it really looks nice and i would like to have it. The whole dark mode idea and process came out of my mind, so i want to finish it. If you have a simpler method how to switch colors feel free to help.